# adding spring-boot-starter-parent to project 'corrupts' resourse filtering

Tags: spring-boot

I have resource plugin configuration in pom.xml in CLI NON-SPRING app:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>  
</build>
```

calling `mvn resources:resources` successfully replaces all ${variables}.

The project got into state, that it would really genefit from inversion of control, so I'd like to throw spring into action here. Step one, add spring parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<!--    <version>2.7.7</version>-->
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

not the same command won't substitute variables, resource filtering does not work.

What am I missing?

I know that spring defines some plugins, and if one want to redefine them, he needs to use same ID for example, but I cannot find the root-problem here. (and note: yes, I know I can avoid referencing spring via parent or use weld/cdi instead, but atm I'd like to get working spring with defined parent)

Answer (score 2):

Remembered the cause thanks to writing to stack overflow used a rubber duck (sorry).

It's caused by that variable pattern is different to avoid conflict between spring and maven variables. Spring redefined variable placeholders. What was: `${project.version}` before is now `@project.version@` or whatever you define, but you cannot use `${}` otherwise spring will 'erase' all variables spring should substitute.

Sorry for pointless question. Keeping it, maybe it will help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only adding spring for IoC then you don't need to add the whole package. I thing you can get away only with:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also the dependency that you have added is used for spring boot projects.